# How can I make a popup show up only if the device is android?

Tags: javascript, php, android, css

I am trying to make a popup appear only if the person that traveled on to the website is using an android device. I have seen this done on other websites but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I am attaching a screenshot of what I am wanting to do.

[image]

Please if anyone can please help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the user agent and if it is an android device, call your code to display a pop up like this:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; 
if(isAndroid) {
    // Call your popup code here
}
```